# Sort list of dictionaries by value, regardless of keyname in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of single entry dictionaries. Each dictionary has only 1 key and 1 value. I'd like to sort the list of dictionaries by these values REGARDLESS of the keyname! The key names are both the same and different from dictionary to dictionary.

All of the online examples I have seen assume the same key name across dictionaries. These type of examples have not worked for me because they assume the same key value:

```
newlist = sorted(list_to_be_sorted, key=lambda k: k['name'])
```

In my example, I need to compare the values regardless of whether the key is bob or sarah; and order the list of dictionaries. Here's an example list of dictionaries:

```
Times = [{"Bob":14.05}, {"Tim":15.09}, {"Tim":17.01}, {"Bob":16.81}, {"Sarah":15.08}]
```

desired output:

```
[{"Bob":14.05}, {"Sarah":15.08}, {"Tim":15.09}, {"Bob":16.81}, {"Tim":1701}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
times = [{"Bob":14.05},{"Tim":15.09},{"Tim":17.01},{"Bob":16.81},{"Sarah":15.08}]
print sorted(times, key=lambda k: k.values())
```

**Output**

```
[{'Bob': 14.05},{'Sarah': 15.08}, {'Tim': 15.09}, {'Bob': 16.81}, {'Tim': 17.01}]
```

If there are multiple values in the `values` list and if you want to consider only the elements at particular index, then you can do

```
print sorted(times, key=lambda k: k.values()[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent at least an hour looking through documentation thinking there just had to be a simple way to do this.

Comment: @StrikePricer You are welcome :) Have fun with python :)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
newlist = sorted(Times, key=lambda k: k.values()[0])
```

It keys off the first (only) of the dictionary's `.values()`

Answer (score 0):

@thefourtheye - your answer is quite nice.

Want to highlight a subtle and IMO interesting thing for folks new to python. Consider this tweak to thefourtheye's answer:

```
times = [{"Bob":14.05},{"Tim":15.09},{"Tim":17.01},{"Bob":16.81},{"Sarah":15.08}]
print sorted(times, key=lambda k: k.itervalues().next())
```

Which yields the same result:

```
[{'Bob': 14.05}, {'Sarah': 15.08}, {'Tim': 15.09}, {'Bob': 16.81}, {'Tim': 17.01}]
```

The tweak avoids the creation of an intermediate and unnecessary array. By using the iterator "itervalues()" and then getting just the first value (via .next()) the sort method just compares the raw value, without the array.

Let's look at performance:

```
test_cases = [
    [],
    [{"Bob":14.05}],
    [{"Bob":14.05},{"Tim":15.09},{"Tim":17.01},{"Bob":16.81},{"Sarah":15.08}],
    [dict(zip((str(x) for x in xrange(50)), random.sample(xrange(1000), 50)))]      # 50 dict's in a list
]
print "perf test"
for test_case in test_cases:
    print test_case

    print "k.values()           :", timeit.repeat(
        "sorted(test_case, key=lambda k: k.values())",
        "from __main__ import test_case",
    )
    print "k.itervalues().next():", timeit.repeat(
        "sorted(test_case, key=lambda k: k.itervalues().next())",
        "from __main__ import test_case",
    )
    print
```

results:

```
[]
k.values()           : [0.7124178409576416, 0.7222259044647217, 0.7217190265655518]
k.itervalues().next(): [0.7274281978607178, 0.7140758037567139, 0.7135159969329834]

[{'Bob': 14.05}]
k.values()           : [1.3001079559326172, 1.395097017288208, 1.314589023590088]
k.itervalues().next(): [1.2579071521759033, 1.2594029903411865, 1.2587871551513672]

[{'Bob': 14.05}, {'Tim': 15.09}, {'Tim': 17.01}, {'Bob': 16.81}, {'Sarah': 15.08}]
k.values()           : [3.1186227798461914, 3.107577085494995, 3.1108040809631348]
k.itervalues().next(): [2.8267030715942383, 2.9143049716949463, 2.8211638927459717]

[{'42': 771, '48': 129, '43': 619, '49': 450, --- SNIP --- , '33': 162, '32': 764}]
k.values()           : [1.5659689903259277, 1.6058270931243896, 1.5724899768829346]
k.itervalues().next(): [1.29836106300354, 1.2615361213684082, 1.267350196838379]
```

Mind you, perf will often not matter, but given that the 2 solutions are similar in terms of readabilty, expressiveness, I think it's good to understand the later solution, and build habits in those terms.